# Web Setup Wizard 404

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, setup

I have Magento 2.2 installed locally using composer on an Apache webserver. Everything seems to be working besides from when I login into the admin and go System -> Web Setup Wizard it takes me to a 404 of /setup

What additional setup did I miss to enable this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/etc/env.php and change the following code from 
`'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'db',
  ),` 
to 
`'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),`

Comment: Is it good to keep this as files for long term? And where are these session files saved?

Comment: yes, You can put this code in app/etc/env.php,
and session files are saved in var/session folder

Comment: I changed the code, but I don't see any files saved in var/session folder.